# SignalR on Core 2.2 fails when deploying to Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I have set up a plain SignalR solution using .NET Core 2.2. I cannot use Core 3.x because I need to use some libraries that depends on 2.2.

It works fine when i debug locally.

However, when I deploy to Azure as an App Service, whenever the JS tries to establish a connection, I can see in Chrome's network tab that it fails when calling /hub/negotiate, and that it returns a 400.

This does not happen locally. Locally I'm running IIS Express, and the server in Azure is running Kestrel.

What I have tried thus far:

- Made sure web sockets is enabled under configuration in Azure. It was already enabled.
- I believe Kestrel is behind a proxy in Azure, so I added `app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto });` at the very top. This had no effect.

I'm not using MessagePack.

Using:

- netcoreapp2.2
- @aspnet/signalr 1.1.4 (is this correct for 2.2? it works locally)

What could be wrong?

Comment: The *correct* client is `@microsoft/signalr`. Why don't you use .NET Core 3.1? What libraries are you using that can only work with 2.2 ? There shouldn't be any problems using a 2.2 library with 3.1. Besides, 2.2 is out of support. It was a point release, not a Long-Term-Support release like 2.1 or 3.1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I thought @microsoft/signalr was for Core 3? I'm using internal libraries created by my company. We are planning to upgrade, but not right now. Have tried using Core 3 with those libraries, but there are massive issues.

Comment: This is a Javascript package, it has nothing to do with .NET Core versions. `aspnet/signlar` is an obsolete package targeting Signlar 1 only. SignalR itself is a .NET Standard library delivered as a NuGet package, and also has nothing to do with .NET Core version. As for the internal projects, have you tried calling them or did you assume they wouldn't work?

Comment: Upgrading to @microsoft/signalr seems to have worked locally. Deployed it, and still it returns 400. I cannot upgrade to Core 3.

Comment: @aspnet/signalr targeted SignalR Core 1 and 2. @microsoft/signalr might then include changes to the protocol which is incompatible with SignalR Core 2.

Comment: @HelloWorld how do you map your hub on the startup?

Answer (score 0):

**I can tell you clearly that there is no problem using `signalr 1.1.4` in `.net core 2.2`.**

It can run normally when deployed in windows and linux. You can [download my test code from github](https://github.com/Jason446620/signalr1.1.4_core2.2), and compare with your project, is there any modification that caused this error?

The proxy settings are not used.

***The only thing to note is:***

I found that when the project is deployed under linux, it takes a while to start normal operation, about three to five minutes. The reason is currently unclear. If you encounter it, you can [raise a support ticket on the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

[image]

[image]

[image]